# Timeout rabbitmq in golang comsumer side

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq and golang, I make a thread for wait message in comsumer side like rabbitmq example. I want to main thread will wait kill signal and send signal to rabbitmq thread, but if message not push in queue, rabbitmq thread wait forever so it not handle kill signal message. 
I found rabbitmq have timeout in comsumer, but I have just found code in java, not golang.
Can you help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to exit out of a routine processings a queue?

The timeout setting won't work here. That's for server/client heartbeats and only kicks in if a heartbeat isn't received in whatever time, but won't do anything for not receiving a frame on the queue.

What I would suggest is something like

```
import "sync"
import "os/signal"

var (
  wg sync.WaitGroup
  sigs = make(chan os.Signal, 1)
  stop = make(chan bool)
)

func main () {

  signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT)

  //your other setup stuff

  wg.Add(2)
  go myQueueProcessor()
  go mySignalProcessor()

  //Now your main will wait for your goroutines to finish here.
  wg.Wait()

  //your program cleanup stuff
}

func myQueueProcessor() {
   defer wg.Done()
  //keep running over the select indefinitely
  for {
    select {
      case <-stop: //if the stop channel is closed exit out of go routine
        return
      case msg := <-sub.C:  //Whatever queue processes you want
         //do message stuff
    }
  }
}

func mySignalProcessor() {
  defer wg.Done()
  select {
    case sig := <-sigs:
      close(stop)
      return
  }
}
```

Now if you send your program a kill signal, it will catch it, close the the stop channel and your queue processing goroutine will exit out and things should shutdown cleanly.